# Difference of normal field extensions to splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In my book "Algebra" by Siegfried Bosch, an algebraic field extension $K\subset L$ ist called normal, if $L$ is a splitting field of a family of polynomials in $K[X]$.

So obviously every splitting field is normal. But also, every normal field extension is a splitting field.

So what exactly is the point of defining a normal field extension, if we already have the notation of a splitting field? Is there anything I did not understand correctly?

Comment: I'd say this is a theorem and at first a [normal extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension) $L/K$ is one such that if $f \in K[X]$ has a root in $L$ then it splits in linear factors in $L[X]$. Also being a splitting field is more useful when it is of some irreducible polynomial (it tells us the possible automorphisms of $L/K$) than of (a family of) non-irreducible polynomials.

Comment: There are other characterizations of normal extensions that don't require making a particular choice of polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension